# CDI: observing select/unselect of a specific type of entity (datatable hierarchies)

Tags: java, events, dependency-injection, cdi, observer-pattern

I have a hierarchy of datatables displayed on a page.

There's a list of `CashValueCalculation` entities that can be selected at the top. If you select one, another datatable of selectable `Paymentstream` entities is shown underneath it. Then again a third time, if you select that kind of entity, a last datatable of `Payment` entities is shown.

There are 3 CDI beans for this: `CashValueCalculationManager`, `PaymentStreamManager` and `PaymentManager`, forming a hierarchy:

```
`CashValueCalculationManager`
    |
    +- `PaymentstreamManager`
        |
        +- `PaymentstreamManager`
```

These beans are supposed to react to their *parent* bean on select/unselect events (UI actually done via a PrimeFaces `p:dataTable` using JSF of course).

Each of the beans inherits from framework classes that have the entity's PK and the entity class itself as generic. Here's some relevant code:

```
public abstract class BaseManager<K, T extends Entity<K>> extends BaseCdiViewBean implements Manager<K, T>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<T> entities;

    private T selectedEntity;
    private EMode mode; // VIEW, ADD, EDIT, REMOVE

    // CDI event producers

    @Inject
    @SingleSelect
    private Event<T> selectEvent;

    @Inject
    @SingleUnselect
    private Event<T> unselectEvent;

    ...

    @Override
    public void setSelectedEntity(T selectedEntity)
    {
        if (selectedEntity == null)
        {
            // null entity not really selectable, interpret as clear selection command
            this.setSelectedEntity(null);

            // fire CDI event to 0-n observers
            this.unselectEvent.fire(this.newEntity()); // cannot pass null to CDI events, use a new entity created from a concrete bean
            return;
        }

        // here we have a non-null selected entity
        this.selectedEntity = selectedEntity;

        // fire CDI event to 0-n observers
        this.selectEvent.fire(selectedEntity);
    }

    ...
}
```

The `Entity` interface is just:

```
public interface Entity<K>
{
    public K getPk();
    public void setPk(K pk);
}
```

The two sub managers `PaymentStreamManager` and `PaymentManager` inherit from `BaseSubManager` and act as observers to their parent managers `CashValueCalculationManager` and `PaymentStreamManager` respectively (that's what they're supposed to):

```
public abstract class BaseSubManager<K, T extends Entity<K>, P extends Entity<?>> extends BaseManager<K, T> implements SubManager<K, T, P>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private P parentEntity;

    @Override
    public P getParentEntity()
    {
        return this.parentEntity;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParentEntity(P parentEntity)
    {
        this.parentEntity = parentEntity;
    }

    public void onSelect(@Observes @SingleSelect P selectedParentEntity)
    {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": selected parent entity: " + selectedParentEntity);
        this.setParentEntity(selectedParentEntity);
    }   

    public void onUnselect(@Observes @SingleUnselect P unselectedParentEntity)
    {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": unselected parent entity: " + unselectedParentEntity);
        this.setParentEntity(null);
    }
}
```

`@SingleSelect` annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface SingleSelect
{
    // no additional interface
}
```

`@SingleUnselect` annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface SingleUnselect
{
    // no additional interface
}
```

What I want now is that `PaymentstreamManager` receives events from `CashValueCalculationManager` and `PaymentManager` receives events from `PaymentstreamManager` **only**.

However, each time I select an entity of the top level manager `CashValueCalculationManager` then both sub managers' `@Observer` methods receive the event (and the method call of course, which is not what I need):

On select test:

```
21:17:34,310 INFO  [stdout] PaymentManager: selected parent entity: CashValueCalculation[pk=2]
21:17:34,312 INFO  [stdout] PaymentStreamManager: selected parent entity: CashValueCalculation[pk=2]
```

On unselect test:

```
21:19:20,176 INFO  [stdout] PaymentStreamManager: unselected parent entity: CashValueCalculation[pk=null]
21:19:20,177 INFO  [stdout] PaymentManager: unselected parent entity: CashValueCalculation[pk=null]
```

**Q**:

Why isn't this working right away? What do I need to change in the code to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Educated guess:

As generics are implemented via type-erasure, you basically have the following events in BaseManager at runtime:

```
@Inject
@SingleSelect
private Event<Object> selectEvent;

@Inject
@SingleUnselect
private Event<Object> unselectEvent;
```

on the other hand, you observe the following:

```
public void onSelect(@Observes @SingleSelect Object selectedParentEntity)
public void onUnselect(@Observes @SingleUnselect Object unselectedParentEntity)
```

... which obviously matches every event.

What I'd try out is, add a class value to the qualifier annotations, something like:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface SingleSelect
{
    public Class<?> value();
}

@Inject
@SingleSelect(SomeConcreteType.class)
private Event<Object> selectEvent;

public void onSelect(@Observes @SingleSelect(SomeConcreteType.class) P selectedParentEntity)
```

This way, your container should be able to distinguish the various events at runtime.